# O(n^2) complexity

Tags: java, big-o

Which one of the following has the`O(n^2 )`complexity

```
public boolean findDuplicates(int[] inputData) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputData.length; j++) {
                if (inputData[i] == inputData[j] && i != j) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

vs

```
public boolean findDuplicates(int[] inputData) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputData.length; j++) {
             System.out.println("...");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

does `if (inputData[i] == inputData[j] && i != j) { return true; }` in the first loop break the complexity of `O(n^2)` as I see I will match only 2 elements if length of the *inputDate* array is 2 .

I'm sorry if this noob question, but what I don't understand is that complexity refers to the total elemens iterated or total of condition satisfied ?

and how about this one (assuming We don't have to calculate the exact complexity, and assuming we ignore *index out of bounds* in the inner loop), is this

```
public boolean findDuplicates(int[] inputData) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < inputData.length; j++) {
            ....
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

still `O(n^2)`?

Comment: `if (inputData[i] == inputData[j] && i != j)` its a constant check, so it wont affect big O

Comment: Big-O notation is not my forte, but I believe it has to do with the number of elements that are potentially visited/iterated. In both scenarios, you're iterating through the array for each element in the array - thus both are O(n^2).

Comment: It would affect your Big O if you could prove that you always break early - if there are no duplicates you will effectively run n^2 iteration of the inner loop...

Comment: @assylias I think you are not correct because of O(N * 1/2 * N) = O(N * N)

Comment: @v.ladynev You-re right, I should have said it *could* affect you BIg O - for example if you can prove that you always exit before the 2nd iteration of the outer loop - then it becomes O(N).

Comment: @Bravo Starting the loop from `1` instead of `0` doesn't change anything in terms of bigOh (asymptotic complexity)

Comment: @assylias Yeah, you are right :)

Comment: @assylias the runtime of the first method would also be affected (it would be worse) if he was using a different comparison function, for example comparing strings...

Comment: @MageXy, so `total of possible elements visited`?

Comment: @Bravo: At a basic level, yes. There is a little more nuance that goes into it, but that's a good starting point.

Comment: Ok thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of the methods you posted have O(n^2) complexity. The conditional inside the first one doesn't change the big O.

Comment: But the second one is also `\Omega(n^2)`, hence `\Theta(n^2)`. I think this is what he was interested in.

Comment: One thing we can add is that this is true because the conditional uses a simple comparison function since all elements are `ints`. If, for example, this was an array of `Strings`, the cost for the function with the conditional would be `O(m*n^2)` where `m` is the length of the longest `String` element since the comparison would be `O(m)` instead of `O(1)`

Comment: Without seeing what's inside the inner for-loop in the example from your edit, all we can say is that your code *has a possibility* of being O(n^2)... but it's possible for ti to be less or more.

Answer (score 1):

big O notation describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.

I think it is fairly clear to you that the second scenario will have O(n^2) time complexity.

In the first case, unless you can always ensure that you will find a duplicate in the first k iterations, where k is a constant which does not depend on n, it will have a complexity of O(n) [Since O(kn) where k is a constant, however large, but known, is O(n)]

However, if this k depends on n in any manner (say, you will always find a match in the first half of the array which repeats), or cannot guarantee a match for every run, then the complexity will be O(n^2). [O(n*n/k) = O(n^2) where k is a constant. Here, k is an arbitrary constant which helps find the percentage of array you have to go through before finding the first index of repeating element]

EDIT:

Did not notice your edit earlier. Yes, the third case is also O(n^2) You can also do the following optimization:

```
findDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

The above case also has a complexity of O(n^2), as it will go through the loop for n + n-1 + n-2 + .... + 1 times, which is (n*n+1/2), which is O(n^2)

Comment: No, big O notation describes an UPPERBOUND of the limiting behavior. So for example both of the codes are `O(n^3)`. What really matters is the big Theta. This is the only point (if any) of this problem.

Comment: @Ulrich, in the third case `j` starts from 0 & not incremented with `i` , is that still O(n^2)?

Comment: @WhatsUp: Yes, you are correct in saying that this code runs in O(n^3) time. It also runs in O(n^4) and O(2^n). O(n^2) is also a valid runtime claim. Big-O notation does describe the upperbound on the limiting behavior, and I can always find a large enough cosntant k, which makes k * n * n larger than the actual number of operations. Big theta gives you a tight upper bound, which is \Theta(n^2) in this case.

Comment: @Bravo: What do you mean by not incremented with 'i'?

Comment: I mean `j` starts from `1` in the inner loop , is the third still O(n^2) ?

Comment: yes, it is still O(n^2). Making constant changes does not make any difference. Think of what will happen when the size of array becomes very large. It will have n*(n-1) operations [since it will go through the outer loop n times, and the inner loop will have n-1 operations each time].

Comment: Note that all this is assuming that you perform a constant time function inside the inner loop. Otherwise, that will have to be taken into consideration to find the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

All of above loops are O(n^2). 
algorithms are analyzed normally in best, average and worst case scenarios. 
For your loops with condition: 
   Worst case: O(n^2)
   Best case: Constant time. Because best scenario would be inputData[0]==inputData[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

For your loops without condition:
   Now, it becomes just nested array traversal so, both worst and best case will be O(n^2).

Overall, worst case performance is used for evaluating algorithms but few algorithms works (eg [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)) really well in average case compared to worst case which.